# How to change model and render Marionette view from another view

Tags: javascript, render, marionette

I' ve got LayoutView in Marionette. Give only onRender method:

```js
onRender: function() {            
            this.showChildView("content", new CanvasView({ model: this.model }));
            this.showChildView("library", new LibraryView());
            this.showChildView("properties", new PropertiesView({ model: this.model }));
        }
```

In content there is a model, that contains svg elements(for ex. line, ellipse...) with their properties. I need to change model in PropertiesView. For example I need to change line width or color and rerender "content" child view. How could I do this? 
PropertiesView consists of input sets. For example:

```html
Line color: <input type="text" id="id_2" name="style" value= <%= lineColor %>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Backbone [event system](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). Every time you set anything to your model the `change` event fires.

In PropertiesView you can add some events for user interaction. On every input set it content to model:

```
ui: {
    'style': 'input[name=style]'
},
events: {
    'input @ui.style': 'onInputStyle'
},
onInputStyle: function(){
    this.model.set('style', this.ui.style.val());
}
```

And in CanvasView subscribe to them and change your view accordingly:

```
modelEvents: {
    'change:style': 'onChangeStyle'
},
onChangeStyle: function(){
    this.$el.attr('style', this.model.get('style'));
}
```

Comment: In CanvasView modelEvents is not working. Don't know why

Comment: It is strange, maybe old version of Marionette? Can you also try to add `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:style', this.onChangeStyle)` to CanvasView initialize? And can you check that model is actually changing?

Comment: strange, but I can't get value using `this.ui.style.val()`. I get as a parameter e in onInputStyle function and get value using `e.target.value`. Really strange, your variant works for me on a different attribute. When I use set on `this.model.set("styles", someValues)` modelEvents don't fire up (Actually in my model use **styles** instead of style). I should use `this.model.set("styles", new Backbone.Collection(someValues))`. After that everything works. Thanks anyway, I find out what I need, according to your samples.